# How to make a new matrix from two or more matrix by using column values in R

Tags: r, preprocessor

If i have two data frames
DF1 and DF2

```
> DF1
Date         EMMI      ACT      PM25
2011/02/12   12345     21       12
2011/02/14   14321     22       13
2011/02/19   12345     21       14
2011/02/24   14745     23       18

> DF2
Date         EMMI      ACT      NO2
2011/02/12   12345     21       11
2011/02/14   14321     22       12
2011/02/19   12345     21       13
2011/02/23   43211     13       12
2011/02/23   56341     13       12
```

Can anybody please let me know how to join these two data frames. by matching date and EMMI. So i want all similar dates and EMMI should be on the same rows. If they do not match then NAs should be present some thing like

```
> DF3
Date         EMMI      ACT      NO2   pm25
2011/02/12   12345     21       11    12
2011/02/14   14321     22       12    13
2011/02/19   12345     21       13    14
2011/02/23   43211     13       12    NA
2011/02/23   56341     13       12    NA
2011/02/24   14745     23       NA    18
```

Comment: Yep, the answer (basically, use `merge()`) is pretty hard to miss with any search along the lines of "join dataframes"